# Eyeballs become invisible when inserting into retopologized head

Tags: mesh, objects, sculpting, retopology

I am a beginner at Blender. This sculpture is my very first.

Base sculpture: https://twitter.com/DariaWinnicka/status/1516069031673012224

I have since completed retopology: https://twitter.com/DariaWinnicka/status/1575455988655734786

And, completed the transition (deletion of the original mesh and centring the retopology mesh).

**Problem:**

- Original mesh and retopology mesh side by side: https://twitter.com/DariaWinnicka/status/1576271993590394880
- If I'm able to, I'd like to use the original sculpture's eyeballs for the retopology sculpture.
- I moved the eyeballs accordingly. However, when the eyeballs hover in front of the sculpture, they become invisible.
- I'd like the eyeballs to be located in the same location and appear the same as the original sculpture's eyeballs (refer to the above link).

**Please watch the video to understand further:** https://youtu.be/0Av52Hp4SjE

I appreciate all the help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please be so kind and try to ask your question in such a way that all necessary information is visible here and the question is unambiguous and detailed. Please try to avoid external links! If you use images (which I recommend) then include them here directly via the editor. In some cases (including this one) it is helpful if you attach the blend file. But please be so kind and use https://blend-exchange.com/, so that these files are preserved and there are no dead links one day.

Comment: Agreed. Instructions for embedding images in questions are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post).

Comment: My guess is that you still have enabled the option *[Object Properties > Viewport Display > In Front](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/display.html)* for the retopologized mesh.